# Add quotes around each word

Tags: java, regex

I want to transform in Java:

dd fdas dd fdas fads f das fdasf + - || dasf
  into:
"dd" "fdas" "dd" "fdas" "fads" "f" "das" "fdasf" + - || "dasf"

basically I want to add quotes around words.
\w* -> "\w*\"

Comment: Note that `\w` includes digits, so `some number 334` would become `"some" "number" "334"`

Comment: Yes:\w  A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]

Comment: is there a good reason for this, adding quotes/double quotes is normally a bad smell ... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) can do this:

```
String result = input.replaceAll("(\w+)", "\"$1\"");
```

Comment: You should group the word to use it in the replace

Comment: @Colin, Konrad You could use `$0` if you're not grouping it. So `replaceAll("\w+", "\"$0\"")` <- this works in .Net - I don't know for sure that the syntax is equivalent in Java.

Comment: @lasse: That should work too. I prefer explicit grouping, though.

Comment: I though I won't get grouping in replaceAll. +1 for Java

Comment: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
in java7

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple. Use preg_replace and sorround all text captures with quotes.

```
preg_replace("/([a-z0-9]+)/i", '"$1"', $string);
```

You will have to find the replacement of preg_replace for java :)