# Transform plain text into Json - Java - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to transform a text string `str = {Message={description=Data Loading Success}}` into a Json format, so I can use Gson to translate the resulting json in a Java class.

So far I used  `String formattedResponse = str.replace("=", ":");` and got `{Message:{description:Data Loading Success}}` but I have no idea how to add the `"` and finally get `{"Message": {"description": "Data Loading Success"}}`

Comment: Try using : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838750/5031209

Comment: There a reason you're not using a library to do this? (eg jackson)

Comment: What's you goal / reason why you are trying to fix invalid JSON. Aren't you able to solve the real problem and receive/handle only valid input? If you receive an invalid JSON string simple throw an InvalidJsonException (and http invalid request / invalid content)

Comment: @Vishal that gets me an ERROR  illegal escape character

Comment: @JasperHuzen I need to handle this response, which is an output from another API over which I have no control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        String str = "{Message={description=Data Loading Success}}";
        String result = str.replaceAll("((\\w\\s*)+)", "\"$1\"");
        System.out.println(result);
        str= "TEST:STRING";
        result = str.replaceAll("((\\w\\s*)+)", "\"$1\"");
        System.out.println(result);
```

Using this I get the results:

```
{"Message"={"description"="Data Loading Success"}}
"TEST":"STRING"
```